# Count dates in one chart with PowerPivot.

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, pivot-chart

I am trying to do some analysis with MS Excel PowerPivot. I have a table, let's call it `tb_policies`. This table has the columns `start_date` and `end_date` and
I need a single chart that shows the count of started AND ended policies for a period of time.

One chart for the count of started and one for the ended policies (maybe grouped by month) is no problem. But how can I bring then together in one without losing the pivot-opportunities (like dynamic filtering etc)?

Comment: Your question is not very clear I'm afraid. How is the period of time specified (e.g. is there a second table with a list of start and end dates? Is it just the 'start_date' or 'end_date' columns which are used?

Answer (score 0):

@Soulus101 The dates are only in `tb_policies`. It looks like this:

[Image_tb_policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERmPG.png)

The grath I want to create is "count of started policies" vs. "count of ended policies"
Like this:
[Image_chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDylp.png)

(Sorry, its not allowed to me to post inline images)